# How can I actually use std::chrono types without risking overflow and undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow, c++-chrono

I've used `std::chrono` for years and have watched many of Howard Hinnant's
talks on the design and use of the library.  I like it, and I think I generally
understand it.  However, recently, I suddenly realized that I didn't know how to
use it *practically* and *safely* to avoid undefined behaviour.

Please bear with me while I walk through a few cases to set the stage for my
question.

Let's start with what I think is the "simplest" `std::chrono::duration` type,
`nanoseconds`.  Its minimum `rep` size is 64-bit, which means in practice it
will be `std::int64_t` and there are thus probably no "leftover" optional
representational bits that aren't required to be there by the standard.

This function is obviously not always safe:

```
nanoseconds f1(nanoseconds value)
{ return ++value; }
```

If `value` is `nanoseconds::max()`, then this overflows, which we can confirm
with clang 7's UBSan (`-fsanitize=undefined`):

```
runtime error: signed integer overflow: 9223372036854775807 + 1 cannot be
represented in type 'std::__1::chrono::duration<long long,
std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> >::rep' (aka 'long long')
```

But this is nothing special.  It's no different than the typical integer case:

```
std::int64_t f2(std::int64_t value)
{ return ++value; }
```

When we can't be sure that `value` isn't already its maximum, we check first,
and handle the error however we deem appropriate.  For example:

```
nanoseconds f3(nanoseconds value)
{
  if(value == value.max())
  {
    throw std::overflow_error{"f3"};
  }
  return ++value;
}
```

If we have an existing (unknown) `nanoseconds` value that we want to add another
(unknown) `nanoseconds` value to, the naive approach is:

```
struct Foo
{
  // Pretend this can be set in other meaningful ways so we
  // don't know what it is.
  nanoseconds m_nanos = nanoseconds::max();

  nanoseconds f4(nanoseconds value)
  { return m_nanos + value; }
};
```

And again, we'll get into trouble:

```
runtime error: signed integer overflow: 9223372036854775807 +
9223372036854775807 cannot be represented in type 'long long'
Foo{}.f4(nanoseconds::max()) = -2 ns
```

So, again, we can do as we would with the integers, but it's already getting
trickier because these are signed integers:

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(nanoseconds nanos = nanoseconds::max())
    : m_nanos{nanos}
  {}
  // Again, pretend this can be set in other ways, so we don't
  // know what it is.
  nanoseconds m_nanos;

  nanoseconds f5(nanoseconds value)
  {
    if(m_nanos > m_nanos.zero() && value > m_nanos.max() - m_nanos)
    {
      throw std::overflow_error{"f5+"};
    }
    else if(m_nanos < m_nanos.zero() && value < m_nanos.min() - m_nanos)
    {
      throw std::overflow_error{"f5-"};
    }
    return m_nanos + value;
  }
};

Foo{}.f5(0ns) = 9223372036854775807 ns
Foo{}.f5(nanoseconds::min()) = -1 ns
Foo{}.f5(1ns) threw std::overflow_error: f5+
Foo{}.f5(nanoseconds::max()) threw std::overflow_error: f5+
Foo{nanoseconds::min()}.f5(0ns) = -9223372036854775808 ns
Foo{nanoseconds::min()}.f5(nanoseconds::max()) = -1 ns
Foo{nanoseconds::min()}.f5(-1ns) threw std::overflow_error: f5-
Foo{nanoseconds::min()}.f5(nanoseconds::min()) threw std::overflow_error: f5-
```

I *think* I got that right.  It's starting to get harder to be certain if the
code is correct.

So far, things might seem manageable, but what about this case?

```
nanoseconds f6(hours value)
{ return m_nanos + value; }
```

We have the same problem as we did with `f4()`.  Can we solve it the same way as
`f5()` did?  Let's use the same body as `f5()`, but just change the argument
type, and see what happens:

```
nanoseconds f7(hours value)
{
  if(m_nanos > m_nanos.zero() && value > m_nanos.max() - m_nanos)
  {
    throw std::overflow_error{"f7+"};
  }
  else if(m_nanos < m_nanos.zero() && value < m_nanos.min() - m_nanos)
  {
    throw std::overflow_error{"f7-"};
  }
  return m_nanos + value;
}
```

This seems sane because we're still checking if there's room between
`nanoseconds::max()` and `m_nanos` to add in `value`.  So what happens when we
run this?

```
Foo{}.f7(0h) = 9223372036854775807 ns
/usr/lib/llvm-7/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:880:59: runtime error: signed
integer overflow: -9223372036854775808 * 3600000000000 cannot be represented
in type 'long long'
Foo{}.f7(hours::min()) = 9223372036854775807 ns
Foo{}.f7(1h) threw std::overflow_error: f7+
Foo{}.f7(hours::max()) DIDN'T THROW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Foo{nanoseconds::min()}.f7(0h) = -9223372036854775808 ns
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::overflow_error: f7-
Aborted
```

Oh my.  That definitely didn't work.

In my test driver, the UBSan error is printed above the call that it is
reporting on, so the first failure is `Foo{}.f7(hours::min())`.  But that case
shouldn't even throw, so why did it fail?

The answer is that even the act of *comparing* `hours` to `nanoseconds` involves
a conversion.  This is because the comparison operators are implemented via the
use of `std::common_type`, which `std::chrono` defines for `duration` types in
terms of the greatest common divisor of the `period` values.  In our case,
that's `nanoseconds`, so first, the `hours` is converted to `nanoseconds`.  A
snippet from `libc++` shows part of this:

```
template <class _LhsDuration, class _RhsDuration>
struct __duration_lt
{
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR
  bool operator()(const _LhsDuration& __lhs, const _RhsDuration& __rhs) const
  {
    typedef typename common_type<_LhsDuration, _RhsDuration>::type _Ct;
    return _Ct(__lhs).count() < _Ct(__rhs).count();
  }
};
```

Since we didn't check that our `hours` `value` was small enough to fit in
`nanoseconds` (on *this* particular standard library implementation, with its
particular `rep` type choices), the following are essentially equivalent:

```
if(m_nanos > m_nanos.zero() && value > m_nanos.max() - m_nanos)

if(m_nanos > m_nanos.zero() && nanoseconds{value} > m_nanos.max() - m_nanos)
```

As an aside, the same problem will exist if `hours` uses a 32-bit `rep`:

```
runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 * 3600000000000 cannot be
represented in type 'long long'
```

Of course, if we make the `value` small enough, including by limiting the `rep`
size, we can end up making it fit . . . since obviously *some* `hours` values
can be represented as `nanoseconds` or conversions would be pointless.

Let's not give up yet.  Conversions are another important case anyway, so we
should know how to handle them safely.  Surely that can't be too hard.

The first hurdle is that we need to know if we can even get from `hours` to
`nanoseconds` without overflowing the `nanoseconds::rep` type.  Again, do as we
would with integers and do a multiplication overflow check.  For the moment,
let's ignore negative values.  We could do this:

```
nanoseconds f8(hours value)
{
  assert(value >= value.zero());
  if(value.count()
     > std::numeric_limits<nanoseconds::rep>::max() / 3600000000000)
  {
    throw std::overflow_error{"f8+"};
  }
  return value;
}
```

It seems to work if we test it against the limits of our standard library's
choice of `nanoseconds::rep`:

```
f8(0h) = 0 ns
f8(1h) = 3600000000000 ns
f8(2562047h) = 9223369200000000000 ns
f8(2562048h) threw std::overflow_error: f8+
f8(hours::max()) threw std::overflow_error: f8+
```

But, there are some pretty serious limitations.  First, we had to "know" how to
convert between `hours` and `nanoseconds`, which kind of defeats the point.
Secondly, this only handles these very particular two types with a very nice
relationship between their `period` types (where only a single multiplication is
needed).

Imagine we wanted to implement an overflow-safe conversion of just the standard
named `duration` types, supporting only the lossless conversions:

```
template <typename target_duration, typename source_duration>
target_duration lossless(source_duration duration)
{
  // ... ?
}
```

It seems like we need to compute relationships between ratios and make decisions
and check the multiplications based on that . . . and once we've done that,
we've had to understand and re-implement all of the logic in the `duration`
operators (but now with overflow safety) that we originally set out to use in
the first place!  We can't really need to implement the type just to use the
type, can we?

Plus, when we're done, we just have some function, `lossless()`, that performs a
conversion if we explicitly call it instead allowing natural implicit
conversions, or some other function that adds a value if we explicitly call it
instead of using `operator+()`, so we've lost the expressiveness that is a huge
part of the value of `duration`.

Add into the mix lossy conversions with `duration_cast` and it seems hopeless.

I'm not even sure how I would approach dealing with something as simple as this:

```
template <typename duration1, typename duration2>
bool isSafe(duration1 limit, duration2 reading)
{
  assert(limit >= limit.zero());
  return reading < limit / 2;
}
```

Or, worse, this, even if I knew some things about `grace`:

```
template <typename duration1, typename duration2>
bool isSafe2(duration1 limit, duration2 reading, milliseconds grace)
{
  assert(limit >= limit.zero());
  assert(grace >= grace.zero());
  const auto test = limit / 2;
  return grace < test && reading < (test - grace);
}
```

If `duration1` and `duration2` can really be any `duration` type (including
things like `std::chrono::duration<std::int16_t, std::ratio<3, 7>>`, I can't see
a way to proceed with confidence.  But even if we limit ourselves to "normal"
`duration` types, there are a lot of scary outcomes.

In some ways this situation is no "worse" than dealing with normal fixed-size
integers, like everyone does every day, where you often "ignore" the possibility
of overflow because you "know" the domain of values you're working with.  But,
surprisingly to me, these types of solutions seem "worse" with `std::chrono`
than they do with normal integers because as soon as you try to be safe with
respect to overflow, you end up defeating the benefits of using `std::chrono` in
the first place.

If I make my own `duration` types based on an unsigned `rep`, I guess I
technically avoid at least some of the undefined behaviour from an integer
overflow point of view, but I still can easily get garbage results from
"careless" calculations. The "problem space" seems to be the same.

I'm not interested in a solution based on floating point types.  I'm using
`std::chrono` to keep the precise resolutions I choose in each case.  If I
didn't care about being precise or rounding errors, I could easily just use
`double` to count seconds everywhere and not mix units.  But if that was a
viable solution for every problem, we wouldn't have `std::chrono` (or even
`struct timespec`, for that matter).

So my question is, how do I safely and practically use `std::chrono` to do
something as simple as add two values together of different durations without
fear of undefined behaviour because of integer overflow?  Or do lossless
conversions safely?  I haven't figured out a practical solution even with known
simple `duration` types, let alone the rich universe of all possible `duration`
types.  What am I missing?

Comment: "*safely and practically*" Define safe and practical. While the code you put forth may be "safe" in some sense of the word (though not in reality, since throwing exceptions is hardly "safe"), what you're doing is *far* from "practical". A 64-bit integer, storing nanosecond precision, can handle centuries of time before overflowing. Cut it down to microseconds, and you can handle hundreds of millennia. The level of checking you're doing is not practical, when analyzed relative to the likelihood of encountering an actual problem. So what do you find "practical"?

Comment: I agree that nothing I show is practical.  That's why I am asking the question.  By safe, I mean essentially how can I check if a value of arbitrary duration can be added to some other value of a different duration (for example)? If the only answer is "you just have to know a priori that it fits", that doesn't really seem practical to me.  But I am willing to accept that I am missing something important here or coming at this from the wrong angle. (Throwing exceptions is beyond the point here.  It just one example of "handling overflow".  Substitute whatever other behaviour you see fit.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The highest performing answer is to know your domain, and don't program anywhere near the maximum range of the precision you're using.  If you're using `nanoseconds`, the range is +/- 292 years.  Don't go near that far.  If you need more range than just +/- 100 years, use a coarser resolution than nanoseconds.

If you can follow those rules, then you can just not worry about overflow.

Sometimes you can't.  For example if your code must handle untrusted input, or general input (e.g. a general purpose library), then you really do need to check for overflow.

One technique is to choose a `rep` just for comparison that can handle more range than anyone needs, just for the comparison.  `int128_t` and `double` are two tools I reach for in this case.  For example, here is a `checked_convert` that checks for overflow using `double` prior to actually performing the `duration_cast`:

```
template <class Duration, class Rep, class Period>
Duration
checked_convert(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> d)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using S = duration<double, typename Duration::period>;
    constexpr S m = Duration::min();
    constexpr S M = Duration::max();
    S s = d;
    if (s < m || s > M)
        throw std::overflow_error("checked_convert");
    return duration_cast<Duration>(d);
}
```

It is significantly more expensive.  But if you are writing (for example) `std::thread::sleep_for`, it is worth the expense.

If for some reason you can't using floating point even for checks, I have experimented with `lcm_type` (not a great name).  This is the opposite of `common_type_t<Duration1, Duration2>`.  Instead of finding the `duration` that both input `duration`s can convert to without loss (without a division), it finds the `duration` that both input `duration`s can convert to without a multiplication.  For example `lcm_type_t<milliseconds, nanoseconds>` has type `milliseconds`.  *Such a conversion can not overflow.*

```
template <class Duration0, class ...Durations>
struct lcm_type;

template <class Duration>
struct lcm_type<Duration>
{
    using type = Duration;
};

template <class Duration1, class Duration2>
struct lcm_type<Duration1, Duration2>
{
    template <class D>
    using invert = std::chrono::duration
                   <
                       typename D::rep,
                       std::ratio_divide<std::ratio<1>, typename D::period>
                   >;

    using type = invert<typename std::common_type<invert<Duration1>,
                                                  invert<Duration2>>::type>;
};

template <class Duration0, class Duration1, class Duration2, class ...Durations>
struct lcm_type<Duration0, Duration1, Duration2, Durations...>
{
    using type = typename lcm_type<
                     typename lcm_type<Duration0, Duration1>::type,
                     Duration2, Durations...>::type;
};

template <class ...T>
using lcm_type_t = typename lcm_type<T...>::type;
```

You can convert both input durations to `lcm_type_t<Duration1, Duration2>`, without fear of overflow, then do the comparison.

The problem with this technique is that it is not precise.  Two slightly different durations might convert to the `lcm_type_t` and because of truncation losses, compare equal.  For this reason I prefer the solution with `double`, but it is good to have `lcm_type` in your toolbox too.

Comment: Both parts of this answer make sense to me.  "Know it won't overflow if you can, but if you can't here's how to check.". I think in practice, in many cases,  most such checking will be near the edges, in order to maintain the invariant of values being small enough to not overflow.  A bit of special case checking where it counts might be plenty.  Thanks.